# Linking Docker Apache Hadoop and Docker Apache Kafka

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

i'm new to apache **hadoop** and **kafka**, i would like to setup them by **docker** container and link each other.

The scenario may look like:

**(docker kafka) <-> (docker hadoop)**

But seriously, i can't find a tutorial which teach me to configure to link them on docker. Can somebody give me a link to the tutorial, or explain me how to do it please.

Sorry if this question is so weird for you, i'm just a noob. Thank in advance

Comment: I am also looking to build the same. Any luck?